# Library or tool to point out floating point arithmetic issues on a code snippet

Tags: library

I am looking for a library or a standalone tool that can verify my code (written in C++) and point out issues (if any) related to floating point arithmetic.

My colleague is sure of the presence of one such library, but he cannot recall the name at the moment.

Will prefer a free solution, but do not hesitate to recommend if you're aware of a paid one.

EDIT:
One such issue could be divide-by-zero exceptions. Consider the following snippet:

```
double y = x - 1;
auto val = x / y;
```

The library in question must print something like:

> will throw exception for x=1

Comment: *issues related to floating point arithmetic* - what could those be? The only ones I see are rounding errors and they depend on values assigned at run time, so amount of code checking is going to help there.

Comment: @JanDoggen updated the question